# Create a function column that is the result of OR between 3 columns

Tags: oracle, computed-column

I have a table with 3 columns (A,B,C).

In each row, only one of the columns is not null.

How do I create a function column or a computed column that will consist from all the non null values?

Something like: column(A or B or C)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for virtual columns is very simple:

```
ALTER TABLE tableX
  ADD abc AS (COALESCE(a, b, c)) ;
```

Tested at [rextester.com](http://rextester.com/RJAKYY18365).